# django rest framework offline documentation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to get the documentation for django rest framework for offline usage, Why? b/c I live in Ethiopia and the internet is too damn slow for me to go online just to the doc of `APIView`. So does anybody know of a link where I can find the offline version of the documentation? The pdf on [readthedoc](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/django-rest-framework/3.4.7/django-rest-framework.pdf) is outdated and empty and I can't seem to find any other alternative.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The documentation for DRF is contained within the main repo. You can use `mkdocs serve` to serve the documentation locally.

Checkout the DRF repo:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework.git
cd django-rest-framework
```

Install and run `mkdocs`. You must do this in the above directory which contains `mkdocs.yml`.

```sh
pip install mkdocs
mkdocs serve
```

Visit http://127.0.0.1:8000 in your web browser.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me as directed.

Answer (score 5):

Go to https://devdocs.io, head to preference and install DRF documentation.

devdocs.io is a PWA, you can open it when you're offline and access DRF documents.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).